# Function : Assign value from an attribut to a variable inside DECLARE

Tags: postgresql, function

I want to assign a value to a variable inside my DECLARE block like in this function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(place_id INTEGER, num int) RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
        initial_price int = num * place_id.price; --error here
    BEGIN
        --stuff to do
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get this error :

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "place_id"

My place_id is an ID from a table that got an attribut 'price int'. I don't understand my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mis-use a function.  It appears that you want to use a Procedure.  Also, having a value from a ID field within a table does not mean that you can reference a table with it.

Comment: how could I get to my attribut from my ID ? The only way is to do a SELECT INTO my_var?

Comment: If you want to get additional field values from elsewhere you can populate local var  within a function by using a 'SELECT * into local_variable from tablename WHERE some conditional' clause but you must do so in the main body of the function after the DECLARE section.  Use a function only if you intend to provide a result.  Your definition above says the return  type is void. If you are intent on using a function then you should change the return type to 'int' and ensure you return some result to indicate success or failure.

Comment: reference this documentation for more details [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html]